# Android Studio fails to resolve / index imported modules correctly

Tags: android-studio, indexing, gradle, import, module

My project setup:
app -- (android project)  -- requires both module A and module B

moduleA( java library gradle project)  -- 
moduleB ( java library gradle proejct) -- depends on module A

If I import module A, either through the IDE(import gradle project), 
or by editing the build.gradle / settings files of my 
android project,  no issue,  it will import correctly, compile/index
just fine.  I am able to navigate to the contained classes..etc

When I import module B through the IDE, I get an jetbrains.android 
plugin error that it could not save the settings. 
Upon reboot, many other plugin errors occur .

IF I import module B by manually editing the apps build file, and 
settings file,  The system will compile just fine.  However,
it will not index/resolve properly, making editing a pain...

The only difference between module A and B.  is that B has 
a gradle settings file within it, which contains its dependency 
on A.
I have tested this out on other module which contain dependencies, and 
the exact same issue occurs.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.